# Emails won't send after upgrading from Django 1.6.x to Django > 1.7.x

Tags: django, email

I am currently using Django Allauth and a modified version of Django Invitations (https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations). The only thing added is a field for which group to add the user to, and the application works perfectly when Django 1.6.x is being used. I would like to upgrade to Django 1.7.x or 1.8 but this somehow breaks the emailing feature.

The specific piece of code is here:

```
'import datetime

 from django.db import models
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
 from django.utils import timezone
 from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
 from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
 from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

 from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
 from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter

 from .managers import InvitationManager
 from . import app_settings
 from . import signals

 ...(other code)

 def send_invitation(self, request, **kwargs):
    current_site = (kwargs['site'] if 'site' in kwargs
                    else Site.objects.get_current())
    invite_url = reverse('invitations:accept-invite',
                         args=[self.key])
    invite_url = request.build_absolute_uri(invite_url)

    ctx = {
        'invite_url': invite_url,
        'current_site': current_site,
        'email': self.email,
        'key': self.key,
    }

    email_template = 'invitations/email/email_invite'

    get_adapter().send_mail(email_template,
                            self.email,
                            ctx)
    self.sent = timezone.now()
    self.save()
    signals.invite_url_sent.send(
        sender=self.__class__,
        instance=self,
        invite_url_sent=invite_url)'
```

found here (https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations/blob/master/invitations/models.py)

This also references the code from allauth here:

```
 from __future__ import unicode_literals import re
 import warnings
 import json

 from django.conf import settings
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.template.loader import render_to_string
 from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
 from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
 from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives, EmailMessage
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib import messages

 try:
     from django.utils.encoding import force_text
 except ImportError:
     from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode as force_text

 from ..utils import (import_attribute, get_user_model,
                 generate_unique_username,
                 resolve_url)

 from . import app_settings

 USERNAME_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', re.UNICODE)

 ........ (other code)

 def render_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
    """
    Renders an e-mail to `email`.  `template_prefix` identifies the
    e-mail that is to be sent, e.g. "account/email/email_confirmation"
    """
    subject = render_to_string('{0}_subject.txt'.format(template_prefix),
                               context)
    # remove superfluous line breaks
    subject = " ".join(subject.splitlines()).strip()
    subject = self.format_email_subject(subject)

    bodies = {}
    for ext in ['html', 'txt']:
        try:
            template_name = '{0}_message.{1}'.format(template_prefix, ext)
            bodies[ext] = render_to_string(template_name,
                                           context).strip()
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            if ext == 'txt' and not bodies:
                # We need at least one body
                raise
    if 'txt' in bodies:
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                                     bodies['txt'],
                                     settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                                     [email])
        if 'html' in bodies:
            msg.attach_alternative(bodies['html'], 'text/html')
    else:
        msg = EmailMessage(subject,
                           bodies['html'],
                           settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                           [email])
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'  # Main content is now text/html
    return msg

def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
    msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
    msg.send()'
```

found at (allauth/account/adapter.py)

The form always saves an invitation element into the database but breaks at the sending email line. (all infor stored is correct, so that isn't breaking it). If the email is removed, all code afterwards runs fine. I have even tried to just send a basic email like such in place:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
msg = EmailMessage("TEST", "HELLO", my_email, [some_email])
msg.send()
```

but this, too does not send emails.

I am hoping this is super simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any error? What is the value of your [EMAIL_BACKEND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#email-backend) setting?

Comment: Can you give the stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the execution just hung when running this code in a django shell (Django 1.7):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Following the [Django docs on email settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_USE_TLS), I used in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

This worked.